# View rows and tables for my data in Graphcool?

Tags: graphcool

With Graphcool is it possible to view the SQL database to see your tables, rows, items etc?

My application will use GraphQL queries (obviously!) but as an admin it would be handy for me to be able to see my entire database.

```
{
  allGroups{
    name
    id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal run `graphcool console` from your server directory. There is then a data menu link in the page that opens.